# JS - React Native - Expo: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm pretty puzzled why this isn't a valid export; this is from an expo react native application.

This is the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_MainSettingsPage.default')
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

[[image]]

This is my config file that the error is pointting to:

```
import { SettingsPage, ListenPage, MainSettingsPage, DepositePage } from './views'

export const BOTTOM_TAB_INITIAL_PAGE = 'listenPage'

export const BOTTOM_TAB_ROUTES = [
    { iconName: 'ear-outline', iconSize: 32, component: ListenPage, name: 'settingsPage' },
    { iconName: 'ios-settings', iconSize: 32, component: SettingsPage, name: 'listenPage' }
]

export const SETTINGS_TAB_ROUTES = [
    { name: 'mainSettingsPage', component: MainSettingsPage },
    { name: 'depositPage', component: DepositePage }
]
```

When I change the order of`SETTINGS_TAB_ROUTES` and `BOTTOM_TAB_ROUTES` in the config file, I then get the same error for `SETTINGS_TAB_ROUTES`.

Comment: I guess you have wrong export on MainSettingsPage or another